# How do I make a post request with a JSON payload to an external API using node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express

I am trying to make a POST request with a JSON payload to an external API using node.

Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var url = require("url");
var http = require("http");

var app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/api', function(req, res) {
  var query = url.parse(req.url, true).query;
  var key = query.key;

  console.log('JSON PAYLOAD:');
  console.log(req.body); **//PAYLOAD COMES THROUGH AS EXPECTED**

  var options = {};

  options = {
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 1234,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
    path: '/api?key=1234'
  };

  var request = http.request(options, function(response) {
    response.setEncoding('utf-8');
    var responseString = '';
    response.on('data', function(data) {
      responseString += data;
    });
    response.on('end', function() {
      var resultObject = JSON.parse(responseString);
      res.json(resultObject);
    });
  });

  request.on('error', function(e) {
  });

  request.write(req.body) **//THIS METHOD SHOULD BE FORWARDING THE PAYLOAD BUT THIS IS NOT THE CASE...**
  request.end();
});
```

The JSON payload comes through as expected from the origin. However I am unable to forward this payload to the external API. 'request.write(req.body)' appears to be the way to do this, however the external API is still receiving a null payload.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Inside the app.post block

```js
var options = {
  host: 'localhost',
  path: '/api?key=1234',
  port: 1234,
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
};

callback = function(response) {
  var str = ''
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
}

var req = http.request(options, callback);

req.write(JSON.stringify(req.body));
req.end();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but unfortunately that did not work.

Comment: I get the following error:
"TypeError: first argument must be a string or Buffer"

I tried changing the payload to a simlpe string but that caused the request to timeout.

Comment: You have to stringify `req.body` and make sure your localhost 1234 server has body parser

Comment: As well you can use needle or request module on npm, its help you handle those parsing internally.